# Fast way of evaluating the second expression only

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix, optimization, time-complexity

Given a `n×n` matrix `X`, three `n×n` diagonal matrices `D1`, `D2`, `D3`, and three `n×1` vectors `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, my goal is to design an efficient way to evaluate each of the following expressions as fast as possible:

`(Exp1) = X·v1+X·X·v2+X·X·X·v3`

`(Exp2) = D1·X·v1+D2·X·X·v2+D3·X·X·X·v3`

For efficiently evaluting `(Exp1)`, I have the following ideas:

I can rewrite `(Exp1)` as follows:

`(Exp1) = X·v1+X·X·v2+X·X·X·v3 = X·(X·(X·v3+v2)+v1)`

Therefore, I can evaluate `(Exp1)` by using **only three** matrix-vector multiplications as follows:

```
y1=X·v3+v2
y2=X·y1+v1
(Exp1)=X·y2
```

However, for efficiently evaluating `(Exp2)` only, I have no idea. Any suggestions or hints are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a better way than to compute the vectors `X.v1`, `X.X.v2` and `X.X.X.v3` separately (6 matrix/vector multiplies) and combining them to `Exp1` and `Exp2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exp1 and Exp2 are two separate problems. For evaluating Exp2 only, is there any faster method?

Comment: @JohnSmith: I am afraid not, as the `Dk` and `vk` are unrelated. Does `X` have any property ?